# Invalid Syntax VBA

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a VBA script that will perform an API request. Every time I run my code it will says:

> Invalid Syntax.

My code is something like this:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
.Open "POST", "http://example.com" , False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.send "grant_type=value&client_id=value&client_secret=value&username=value&password=value&response_type=token"
End With
```

The error is pointing on the line 4.
If I will perform this request in the postman, it is something like this:

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you saying you get a compile-time error?  Or something else?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, I got compile-time error

Comment: That exact code compiles fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

With all similar code we have used, it has been with **v6**:

```vb
CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP60")
```

though we always use early binding having set a reference to: *Microsoft XML, v6.0*